# arguments for callback in jquery plugin are undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-callback

How do you call a function function defined outside a plugin but using arguments inside the plugin.  I have it where the plugin is calling the function but the parameters are undefined.   Inside the plugin the arguments has values.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            type: 0,
            callBack: function () { }
        };
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.find('.list-item').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var txt = $(this).attr('href');
            var id = txt.substring(1, txt.length);
            settings.callBack.call(settings.type, id);  // populated here
        });
        return this;
    };
} (jQuery));

function loadData(type, id) {
    // type and id are undefined
}

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mydiv").myPlugin({ 
            type: 190, 
            callBack: function(){ loadData();}
         });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you replace

```
callBack: function(){ loadData();}
```

By

```
callBack: loadData
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Note the absence of '()' at the end of the function name.

Comment: I also needed to add settings.callBack.call($(this), settings.type, id);

Answer (score 0):

loadData() doesn't provide any arguments while type and id are expected